# Equivalence of events - CDF of distance of randomly chosen points.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

**Problem:**

> The points $X$ and $Y$ are independently and uniformly chosen on a
> segment $[0,a]$. Find the CDF of the distance $D=|X-Y|$.

**Solution:**

*The vector $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed in the square $Q=[0,a]$. The event $D<t$ is the same as the event that the point lies in the strip $S$ between the lines $y=x-t$ and $y=x+t$. So that $F_D(t)=\Pr(D\le t)=|S\cap Q|/|Q|=(2at-t^2)/a^2$ if $0\le t<a$ and $1$ if $t\ge a.$*

**Questions:**

1. Isn't $Q=[0,a]$ a typo? Since this is not a square, it should be $[0,a]\times[0,a]$ right?
2. I need to intuitively see why those two events are the same, that is why $\{D<t\}\Leftrightarrow\{(X=x,Y=y)\in S\}.$

I've drawn a coordinate system with a $Y-$axis and an $X-$axis and marked $a$, $t$ and the chosen coordinates, but how can I myself show that $S$ is that stripe between those two lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very easy.

first do a drawing representing you situation

[image]

The CDF of D is the white area divided by the total area $a^2$...

It is easier to calculate this ara doing the complement

$$F_D(d)=\frac{a^2-(a-d)^2}{a^2}$$

More precisely you CDF is the following

$$ F_D(d) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $d<0$}  \\
\frac{a^2-(a-d)^2}{a^2},  & \text{if $0\leq d<a$ } \\
1, & \text{if $d \geq a$ }
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Yes when It's drawn I do understand it, I understand that if we pick a point in those purple areas then $D>t$ but how did you know that you should use $y=x\pm d?$

Comment: @Parseval : $|X-Y|<d$ is exactly the white region in the square. Separate the  module and you will realize that

Comment: Ok, I now see how ridiculously easy this was and how the brain just shuts of some days. Thank you kind sir!